# Why low noise / low light camera on microscope?

Tags: microscopy

I see plenty of back illuminated CMOS cameras, low noise cameras, high sensitivity cameras for microscopes.

What's the point? Is there a use case for it or is it pure marketing?
We have a lot of light available for microscopy imaging.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've used such cameras for [fluorescence microscopy](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluorescence_microscope) and had to deal with very low-light, high-noise conditions, especially when looking at transient signals like [calcium imaging](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calcium_imaging) or flavoprotein autofluorescence.

In many of these applications additional light would cause photobleaching, and for live-cell imaging additionally cause phototoxicity/death of the imaged cells.

Comment: so it's very specialized. and for fluo it should be CCD, right ? not a CMOS ? or cmos works too ?

Comment: @ker2x I'm not an expert in sensor engineering/physics, but I believe CMOS is more sensitive and can get you single-photon detection which is then amplified immediately, which is necessary to overcome the noise added in digitization.

Comment: @ker2x I wouldn't call fluorescence microscopy "very specialized". It's used in numerous fields, and in some areas of cell biology it's used quite extensively.

Comment: possibly confocal as well ? i don't know the intensity of the lasers

Comment: Confocal cuts light by a ton, yes. Effectively you get two attenuations of the light: going through the confocal first cuts it into a tiny window, then going back through it again cuts the emission light into a tiny window.

Comment: @MattDMo I suspect that ker2x was meaning specialized application for the camera, rather than the technique.

Answer (score 2):

Nearly all modern image sensors are CMOS, and most reasonable-sized sensors are also back illuminated.  Even if you don't need the sensitivity, you're probably still going to use one because that is what you can buy.